# inverse mapping

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I'm trying to understand how to find the coefficients a-h for inverse mapping,
my goal is to program projective transform from scratch.

let assume i have user input 4 coords entered clockwise onto imageA and i want to map imageB.
imageA is 300X300 and imageA is 256X256.

```
function [ result ] = findCoefficients( imageA, imageB )
% finds coefficients for inverse mapping algorithem 
%   takes 2 X 2d vectors each consists of 4 points x,y
%   and returns the coef accroding to reverse mapping function
%
% x y 0 0 1 0 -xx' -yx'
% 0 0 x y 0 1 -xy' -yy'  
%                       y' and x' are in the destination picture;


A = [imageB(1,1) imageB(2,1) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,1)*imageA(1,1) -imageB(2,1)*imageA(1,1); 
0 0 imageB(1,1) imageB(2,1) 0 1 -imageB(1,1)*imageA(2,1) -imageB(2,1)*imageA(2,1);
imageB(1,2) imageB(2,2) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,2)*imageA(1,2) -imageB(2,2)*imageA(1,2);
0 0 imageB(1,2) imageB(2,2) 0 1 -imageB(1,2)*imageA(2,2) -imageB(2,2)*imageA(2,2);
imageB(1,3) imageB(2,3) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,3)*imageA(1,3) -imageB(2,3)*imageA(1,3);
0 0 imageB(1,3) imageB(2,3) 0 1 -imageB(1,3)*imageA(2,3) -imageB(2,3)*imageA(2,3);
imageB(1,4) imageB(2,4) 0 0 1 0 -imageB(1,4)*imageA(1,4) -imageB(2,4)*imageA(1,4);
0 0 imageB(1,4) imageB(2,4) 0 1 -imageB(1,4)*imageA(2,4) -imageB(2,4)*imageA(2,4)];
B = [imageA(1,1); imageA(2,1); imageA(1,2); imageA(2,2); imageA(1,3); imageA(2,3); imageA(1,4); imageA(2,4)];

result = pinv(A)*B;
end
```

i'm getting a strange result it maps the photo however no into the bounding square i have chosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have error in your matrix $A$. According to [this derivation](http://xenia.media.mit.edu/~cwren/interpolator/), the matrix should be:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x' y & -x' y \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x & y & 1 & -y' x & - y' y \\ & & & & \vdots \end{pmatrix}$$

Maybe your matrix is OK, but it depends on how your point vector is organized. In either case, the problem is probably in organization.

Please note that $A$ can easily get singular or near-singular. Solving $Ah=b$ for $h$ using direct inverse of $A$ is numerically quite unstable. You can use either QR decomposition or SVD to solve the linear system.

Even better method is a normalized DLT (Direct Linear Transform) which work with homogenous coordinates and the normalization step works as preconditioning to the above linear system. This is much more stable solution described in [Hartley & Zisserman's book](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/) (p. 88, section 4.1).

Comment: thanks for the answer, what you showed me is perspective tranform, i'm trying to use projective transform so the matrix looks a little different. i saw a solution using SVD. but isn't the whole idea of inverse mapping like this not to use SVD?

Comment: SVD is here just a method for solving linear system - it has nothing to do with mapping.

Comment: I am pretty confident about that matrix form (perspective transform is just an 8-parameter homography or projective transform) since I have used it and studied in H&Z book. Your matrix mixes unrelated parameters.
Of course you can use $A^{-1}$ but this works only if you are sure that your mapping is exactly defined (there are many so called degenerate cases which can be determined with singular values).

Comment: @Libor, I have a hard time understanding why normalizing the data before applying DLT, I read Hartley's book, but still can't understand the math behind it, I post a question http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/10887/4811, hope you can help me with it.

Comment: @loganecolss I have answered the question you linked to the best of my knowledge. For more information, please refer to the H&Z book (they give a simple explanation) or the paper I have linked in the answer.